# Box Shadow not working after placing an overlay

Tags: html, css

I'm using effect 7 for my project which I grabbed from here https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/

The only effect applied is the one inside the effect7 class. But the :before and :after are not showing.

http://prntscr.com/ln6hm2

http://prntscr.com/ln6hzh

```css
.effect7 {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset !important;
}

.effect7:before,
.effect7:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute !important;
  z-index: -1 !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  left: 10px !important;
  right: 10px !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px / 10px !important;
  border-radius: 100px / 10px !important;
}

.effect7:after {
  right: 10px !important;
  left: auto !important;
  -webkit-transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
  transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg) !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="effect7">
... effect7 ...<br>
... effect7 ...<br>
... effect7 ...<br>
... effect7 ...<br>
... effect7 ...<br>
... effect7 ...<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you might want to copy all of the needed css from the examples on css tricks. you are missing the `.box`css with the important `background:#fff;`

Comment: thanks for the suggested format @Dirk